player can't jump in pygame
My player can't jump unless I hold A and then press space when I'm near an edge
import pygame.display
from settings import *


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, surface, groups, collision_sprites):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = surface
        self.display_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()

        # rects
        self.rect = self.image.get_frect(topleft=pos)
        self.old_rect = self.rect.copy()

        # movement
        self.direction = vector()
        self.speed = 400
        self.gravity = 1300
        self.max_gravity = self.gravity * 4
        self.jump = False
        self.jump_height = 1200

        # collisions
        self.collision_sprites = collision_sprites
        self.on_surface = {'floor': False, 'left': False, 'right': False}
        self.surface = pygame.display.get_surface()

    def input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        input_vector = vector(0, 0)

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            input_vector.x += 1
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            input_vector.x -= 1
        self.direction.x = input_vector.normalize().x if input_vector else input_vector.x

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.jump = True

    def move(self, delta_time):
        # horizontal
        self.rect.x += self.direction.x * self.speed * delta_time
        self.collision('horizontal')

        # vertical
        if not self.on_surface['floor'] and any((self.on_surface['left'], self.on_surface['right'])): # if not touching the floor and walls
            self.direction.y = 0
            self.rect.y += self.gravity / 10 * delta_time

        else:
            if self.gravity > self.max_gravity:
                self.gravity = self.max_gravity

            self.direction.y += self.gravity / 2 * delta_time
            self.rect.y += self.direction.y * delta_time
            self.direction.y += self.gravity / 2 * delta_time
            ic(self.direction.y)

        if self.jump:
            if self.on_surface['floor']:
                self.direction.y = -self.jump_height
                ic(self.direction.y, self.direction.y - self.jump_height)

            elif any((self.on_surface['left'], self.on_surface['right'])):
                self.direction.y = -self.jump_height
                self.direction.x = 10 if self.on_surface['left'] else -10
            self.jump = False

        self.collision('vertical')

    def check_contact(self):
        floor_rect = pygame.Rect(self.rect.bottomleft, (self.rect.width, 2))
        left_rect = pygame.Rect(self.rect.topleft + vector(-2, self.rect.height / 4), (2, self.rect.height / 2))
        right_rect = pygame.Rect(self.rect.topright + vector(0, self.rect.height / 4), (2, self.rect.height / 2))

        collide_rects = [sprite.rect for sprite in self.collision_sprites]
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, "yellow", floor_rect)

        # collisions
        self.on_surface['floor'] = True if floor_rect.collidelist(collide_rects) >= 0 else False
        self.on_surface['left'] = True if left_rect.collidelist(collide_rects) >= 0 else False
        self.on_surface['right'] = True if right_rect.collidelist(collide_rects) >= 0 else False

    def collision(self, axis):
        for other_sprite in self.collision_sprites:
            if other_sprite.rect.colliderect(self.rect):
                if axis == "horizontal":
                    # left
                    if self.rect.left <= other_sprite.rect.right and self.old_rect.left >= other_sprite.old_rect.right:
                        self.rect.left = other_sprite.rect.right

                    # right
                    if self.rect.right >= other_sprite.rect.left and self.old_rect.right <= other_sprite.old_rect.left:
                        self.rect.right = other_sprite.rect.left

                else:  # vertical

                    if self.rect.bottom >= other_sprite.rect.top and self.old_rect.bottom <= other_sprite.old_rect.top:
                        self.rect.bottom = other_sprite.rect.top

                    if self.rect.top <= other_sprite.rect.bottom and self.old_rect.top >= other_sprite.old_rect.bottom:
                        self.rect.top = other_sprite.rect.bottom

                    self.direction.y = 0

    def update(self, delta_time):
        self.old_rect = self.rect.copy()
        self.input()
        self.move(delta_time)
        self.check_contact()

If I place the jump logic above the gravity logic the jump works but I'm following a tutorial from clear code and it's giving me some problems

what is in the settings?

width, height, tile size and I imported pygame in that file

I would suggest you run your program in debug mode. Put a break point at the beginning of the function move and then execute line by line, checking the values of the variables.  This is the standard procedure when encountering unknown behaviours in your code. Execute line by line until you find a discrepancy between what you expect and what you see.

`import pygame, sys
from pygame.math import Vector2 as vector
from icecream import ic
WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 720
FPS = 60
TILE_SIZE = 64`
This is all it has @burcu

please don't post relevant information in the comments. Edit your question instead.
